# update an object without DetailView Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm looking for a solution to update an object without having to go to the detail page but, just edit it on the page itself. What I want to achieve is when I click on edit: the object becomes a field where I can edit and save it. All the YouTube tutorials show the edit->detail page version.

So a quick/direct edit on the object itself that is on the homepage without leaving the homepage.

I have tried to use the UpdateView on this but then there is separate HTML file necessary, which would result in leaving the homepage. I would like to get some help or tips on this.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    HomePageView, 
    TaskCreateView,
    TaskDeleteView,
    TaskUpdateView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('task_new/', TaskCreateView.as_view(), name='task_new'),
    path('<int:pk>/task_delete/', TaskDeleteView.as_view(), name='task_delete'),
    path('<int:pk>/task_edit/', TaskUpdateView.as_view(), name='task_edit'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, DeleteView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Task

class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_tasks_list'

class TaskCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ['text',]

class TaskDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Task
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

class TaskUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ['text',]
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Todo app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo app</h1>
<ul>
    {% for task in all_tasks_list %}
        <li>{{ task.text }}</li>
        <form action="{% url 'task_delete' task.pk %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Delete"/></form>
        <form action="{% url 'task_edit' task.pk %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Edit"/>
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<form action="{% url 'task_new' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Task(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

Comment: what is location of your template task_form.html

Comment: I didn't create a form.html. Is it necessary to create a separate form.html for the kind of action that I want?

Comment: You'll have to use javascript and ajax calls if you want to have single page application, this would be too broad for question here but you can google it

Answer (score 0):

The error says task_form.html doesn´t exist, default template for an UpdateView. Are you sure it exists? If you want to use another template you have to specify

```
class TaskUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = Task
fields = ['text',]
template_name = 'todoapp/my_template.html'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I only work with one HTML file (home.html). The template_name would bring me to the object detail page (what I don't want). I want to edit the object on the home page itself with the UpdateView if that is possible..

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using generic view you should follow documentation for [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview)

In this particular case you are missing form that UpdateView looks for to render `GET` request

> The UpdateView page displayed to a GET request uses a
>   template_name_suffix of '_form'.

In your particular case it is `todoapp/task_form.html` which you should create

> ```
> <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
>     {{ form.as_p }}
>     <input type="submit" value="Update"> </form>
> ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your insight. I now understand that for the UpdateView there is separate form.html necessary to update it and that is exactly the way I want to avoid.